# How to install ClipGrab in Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak)

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, ppa, 16.10

The output which I get while installing **ClipGrab** using **ppa** is :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
jaggu@jaggu-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-get install clipgrab
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

clipgrab : Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.6) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
jaggu@jaggu-Lenovo-G50-80:~$
```

How do I solve this
problem and install ClipGrab ?

Comment: To install ClipGrab, I recommend you to download its .deb package from https://clipgrab.org and install it from that .deb package either using dpkg or GDebi Package Installer!

Comment: Did you upgrade from Xenial to Yakkety and added that PPA before the upgrade? What's the output of `apt-cache clipgrab libavcodec-extra-53`?

Comment: Make that `apt-cache clipgrab libavcodec-extra-53 libavcodec-extra`.

Comment: sreekanth,  @DavidFoerster means `apt-cache policy clipgrab libavcodec-extra-53 libavcodec-extra` (missing `policy` in the above command)

Comment: i will tried, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below , thats work for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:clipgrab-team/
```